# CSS Image aligning/Safari Issue

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I'm designing a website using Dreamweaver and I'm having some problems with aligning the menu bar.  I'm using an image designed in Photoshop and then exported over to dreamweaver.  The image is to go in the center of the banner as it contains the links to the other pages of the website.  I'm having difficulty center aligning this.  It needs to be center aligned by the middle of the image, not by the left edge of the image.  I have been using this code in CSS to do so:
position: fixed; (The menu bar needs to always be at the top, even when scrolling)
top: 0px;
left: 50%;
margin-right: -50%
transform: translate(-50%, 0%);

This has been working for Google Chrome, but on Safari it doesn't work. The image still aligns by the left margin of the picture.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I have also tried using margin-left: 50%; instead of transform and that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are the browser dimensions the same and is the website responsive?

Comment: No, this is my first time attempting to make a full, professional website so I am still trying to learn how to make it responsive and fit all resolution sizes with proper alignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with the prefix?

```css
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%); 
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't seem to work on safari still.  It still works on Chrome that way but for some reason it still fails to work for Safari.

Comment: CORRECTION: I did get it to work just now using that method.  Thank you very much!